# Change google maps api v2 to v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, hashmap

I've had a gmap api running on my site that has just stop showing the map. I don't know what happened and I didn't create the code it was created by the previous developer. There has to be a solution for this please help. I've provide the function code created by the previous developer.

```html
//XXXX: openInfoWindowHtml
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
/* GOOGLE MAP FUNCTIONS
/*--------------------------------------------------*/

var map, agentMarkers, reoMarkers, officeMarker, currentMarker, bounds, agentIcon, reoIcon, officeIcon;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initAgentMap(lat, lng) {
 lat = isNaN(lat) || lat === null ? 37.4419 : lat;
 lng = isNaN(lng) || lat === null ? -122.1419 : lng;
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions : {
         style : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
     }
 });
 agentMarkers = [];
 reoMarkers = [];
 currentMarker = null;
 bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

 var baseIcon = {
     size : new google.maps.Size(29,25),
     anchor : new google.maps.Point(15,25),
     imageMap : [0, 0, 22, 0, 22, 25, 0, 25]
 };

 agentIcon = {
     size : baseIcon.size,
     anchor : baseIcon.anchor,
     imageMap : baseIcon.imageMap,
     url : "/images/icon_redbook.png"
    };

 reoIcon = {
     size : baseIcon.size,
     anchor : baseIcon.anchor,
     imageMap : baseIcon.imageMap,
     url : "/images/icon_reo.png"
 };

 officeIcon = {
        size : baseIcon.size,
        anchor : baseIcon.anchor,
        imageMap : baseIcon.imageMap,
        url : "/images/icon_office.png"
 };
}

function plotAgent(lat, long, text, id) {
 var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position : point,
     icon : agentIcon,
     anchorPoint : new google.maps.Point(12,0),
     map : map
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  infoWindow.setContent(text);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 });
 agentMarkers[id] = marker;
 bounds.extend(point);
 return marker;
}

function plotREO(lat, long, text, id) {
 var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position : point,
     icon : reoIcon,
     anchorPoint : new google.maps.Point(12,0),
     map : map
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
  infoWindow.setContent(text);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 });
 reoMarkers[id] = marker;
 bounds.extend(point);
 return marker;
}

function plotOffice(lat, long, text) {
 var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position : point,
     icon : officeIcon,
     anchorPoint : new google.maps.Point(12,0),
     map : map
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
  infoWindow.setContent(text);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 });
 officeMarker = marker;
 bounds.extend(point);
 return marker;
}

function showAgent(id) {
 if(currentMarker != id){
  currentMarker = id;
  google.maps.event.trigger(agentMarkers[id], "click");
  map.setZoom(11);
  pnt = agentMarkers[id].getPosition();
  pnt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(pnt.lat() + .02 , pnt.lng());
  map.setCenter(pnt2);
 }

}

function showREO(id) {
 if(currentMarker != id){
  currentMarker = id;
  google.maps.event.trigger(reoMarkers[id], "click");
  map.setZoom(11);
  pnt = reoMarkers[id].getPosition();
  pnt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(pnt.lat() + .02 , pnt.lng());
  map.setCenter(pnt2);
 }
}

function showOffice() {
 if(currentMarker != 'office'){
  currentMarker = 'office';
  google.maps.event.trigger(officeMarker, "click");
  map.setZoom(11);
  pnt = officeMarker.getPosition();
  pnt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(pnt.lat() + .02 , pnt.lng());
  map.setCenter(pnt2);
 }
}
```

I've had a gmap api running on my site that has just stop showing the map. I don't know what happened and I didn't create the code it was created by the previous developer. There has to be a solution for this please help. I've provide the function code created by the previous developer.

Comment: your code snippet doesn't run

Comment: GMarker.openInfoWindowHtml is a [Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2) method, that isn't supported in v3.  The Google Maps Javacript API v2 was deprected and turned off May 19th 2010, replaced with a wrapper for v3, it should not be used for new code.  That said, that isn't being used in your code. Please fix the title of the question to reflect your actual issue.

Comment: Okay could you provide me with how the code should look like. Thank you!!

Comment: I've tried replacing the wrapper for v2 with  wrapper for v3 . I really need a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The v2 Maps API was deprecated in 2010 and was finally turned off in November 2013. You will [need to migrate](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3) to v3 of the JS Maps API. Unfortunately this is not an entirely straightforward process.

Comment: Okay , Could you provide me with an link to how to make this migration happen? I Just need to know what's changed and how can I update my v2 Maps API.

Comment: I linked to the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3) in my answer above.

Comment: I've tried migrating the code from V2 to V3 and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Could someone show what I'm doing wrong?